# When making a Laravel package, how do I register the service provider and alias of dependency packages?

Tags: laravel, package

I'm creating a package for Laravel and I've defined the Notification package (https://github.com/edvinaskrucas/notification) as a dependency for my package.

In /workbench/vendor/package/src/composer.json I have:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "illuminate/support": "4.1.*",
    "edvinaskrucas/notification": "2.*"
}
```

I'm then registering the service provider in my package's service provider's register method (not even sure if this is the right way to do this), and the alias using App::alias.

So in /workbench/vendor/package/src/Vendor/Package/PackageServiceProvider.php I have:

```
public function register()
{
    App::register('Krucas\Notification\NotificationServiceProvider');
    App::alias('Notification','Krucas\Notification\Facades\Notification');
}
```

But I'm still getting "Class 'Notification' not found" exception when attempting to use Notification::info() in a controller or Notification::showAll() in a view.

How do I properly register service providers for my package's dependencies?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had a dependency in a package and didn't want to bother the user with these dependencies, for it was a dependency in a dependency. So this is the solution. Hope it will help you!

```
public function register()
{
    /*
     * Register the service provider for the dependency.
     */
    $this->app->register('LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\OAuth2ServerServiceProvider');
    /*
     * Create aliases for the dependency.
     */
    $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
    $loader->alias('AuthorizationServer', 'LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Facades\AuthorizationServerFacade');
    $loader->alias('ResourceServer', 'LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Facades\ResourceServerFacade');
}
```

Comment: Just fyi, there is no need to get an instance of the AliasLoader class, as the container has a method for adding aliases. `$this->app->alias()` will work the same way :) https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L400

Comment: @samrap The `$this->app->alias()` didn't work for me but the `$loader->alias()` did. That's strange

Comment: `$this->app->alias()` method is misleading it does not take a typical facade alias definition as an argument, but rather the result of the facades `getFacadeAccessor()`. Or so it seems to me.

Comment: `$loader->alias()` worked like a charm. I was wasting a lot time to solve this problem finally found the solution

Comment: I'm developing a package for Laravel 8/9 and including composer dependency registering dependencies in my package provider  is not working for me:
`
    public function register()
    {
         $this->app->register(\Tabuna\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::class);
    }

//gives me: Class 'Tabuna\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider' not found

`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the alias() method on the app to register an alias, but I would consider having your package users register aliases and service providers themselves in the install process. It's a good way of keeping track of the external code that you're using, and a nice way of pulling components out to test things.

Personal opinion of course. :)

Dayle

Comment: Okay, thanks. Hmmm, I see what you're saying. I've never seen other packages do that (i.e. I've only had to add one service provider and one alias to app/config/app.php when installing a package, even if that package has other dependencies). Are these developers likely using App::register and App::alias, rather than your preference of having the user add them in their config?

Comment: I'm still getting Notification class not found exception after adding App::alias (assuming I'm using the right syntax, googled around but can't find any documentation on App::alias?). I've updated my original question. What am I doing wrong? Is it because my controller is in the package namespace?

Answer (score 5):

During package development you should add your package service provider in composer.json file as in the code below. For additional information please consult at Laravel's [Package Discovery](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages#package-discovery).

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\ServiceProvider"
        ],
        "aliases": {
            "Debugbar": "Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Facade"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Dear Bomjon, It would be nice if you add a little bit of explanation for bare code you posted.

Comment: During package development, You should add your package service provider in composer.json file like above in the example, Please check in https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages#package-discovery

Comment: That didn't work for me, even thought it is written in the laravel documentation