# Composer dependency in Laravel 5.x

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm still a bit confused when it comes to creating Laravel packages with dependencies.

While Laravel packages come with updates to `config/app.php` and Composer [does not load repositories recursively](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can't-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md), does this mean using a package requires the user to add providers and aliases for the dependencies as well? That's one for the package taken from http://packagist.org, and another for *each* dependency listed in the package's `require` section.

I'm sure I'm looking at this the wrong way, but as of now do I need to update my `README.md` file with the `providers` and `aliases` for each `require` item I used?

**Update:** Not related to [How do I register the service provider and alias of dependency packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574413/when-making-a-laravel-package-how-do-i-register-the-service-provider-and-alias), but nonetheless very connected. That article makes use of dependencies in the Service Provider which is all good, but I'm wondering if you're *not* doing what that article suggests does it still make sense to list down your dependencies? And if you *do* list them down and follow the article does your user still have to redownload your dependencies?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When making a Laravel package, how do I register the service provider and alias of dependency packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574413/when-making-a-laravel-package-how-do-i-register-the-service-provider-and-alias)

Comment: See update based on comment.